# Connect to secured server with synchronous way iOS

Tags: ios, asynchronous, server

I want to know if there is a way to connect to a secured web service (web server requests username and password to connect and return data) with a synchronous way and how can I pass these two parameters in my code, I used this code :

```
-(void)performRequest{
NSURL * url =[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://firstluxe.com/api/tags/?display=[id,name]&output_format=JSON"];
NSURLRequest * request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

NSURLConnection * connection =[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request
delegate:self];}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{ NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0)
{
    NSURLCredential * cred = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser: @"userName"
                                                        password: @"Password"
                                                     persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
else
{
    //You don't have authentication
}
}
-(BOOL)connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
return YES;
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
//handle errors
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
 html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
jsonFromAFNetworking = html;
NSLog(@" html is %@ ",html);
}
```

It returns the value of from the server correctly, but when I do :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self performRequest];
NSLog(@" jsonFromAFNetworking %@" , jsonFromAFNetworking);
}
```

I get null value, I know that it's because it is an asynchronous action, but I need to use the new value and I don't know how to do it, how can I tell the code to wait until the `[self performRequest]`is executed or how to connect to this server by another way?

Comment: You really should not use synchronous methods to call a web service. When you are building a new app, make it right from the start so you don't run into any issues later. Seriously, don't do it synchronous. ;)

Comment: Yes, there are some ways to make this operation synchronously, but that's a really bad idea. If the network is a little slow, the watchdog process may summarily terminate your app. Instead, put anything that you want to perform after the connection finishes inside the `connectionDidFinishLoading` (or `connection:didFailWithError:`). But do not try to perform the query synchronously.

Comment: synchronous is bad and doing so on UI thread is a (almost) sure-fire way of getting 'crashes'